# Xamarin - Android - SQLite - Which C++ Library?

Tags: c#, android, c++, sqlite, mono

A bit of background...

SQLite is an open source C++ library compiled for multiple platforms. There are several commonly used C# wrappers for this library on several different platforms. Some of the common ones are:

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net.git

https://github.com/mattleibow/Mono.Data.Sqlite.git

https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL.git

Here is my one which is a stripped back fork from SQLite.Net-PCL.

https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/SQLite.Net.Standard.git

There are multiple versioning issues around SQLite on the different platforms, but recently, a big version issue came in to play on the Android platform. You can read about it here:
http://ericsink.com/entries/sqlite_android_n.html

According to Xamarin:
*Note: Due to a change by Google, Android N will now only permit linking to NDK-provided native libraries. libsqlite.so is not an NDK-provided native library. Consequently, existing apps using e.g. Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll will crash when running on Android N. This may include other SQLite-using assemblies, not distributed with Xamarin.Android.
Xamarin.Android 7.0, which is part of Cycle 8, updates Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll to include a custom built version of libsqlite.so, named libsqlite3_xamarin.so.*

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/

So, my questions are: **which Android C++ library should we be using for Android**? **Does the version depend on the version of the Android OS installed**? **Where do we get the C++ library from**?

It sounds as though Google will only allow a customized version of the library. I guess this means that they will only accept signed libraries and the one compiled from Xamarin will be accepted. If this is the case, **how do we get this library and package it up in a .NET Standard DLL, or include it in an Android app package**?

I ask this question because this issue has been pointed out in my library here:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/SQLite.Net.Standard/issues/5

I feel like this is connected to the versioning issue. Anything that can shed some light on this would help. In my repo mentioned above, I have created a branches called Issues/5 which uses a different C++ library called libsqlite3_xamarin which seems to be bundled with Mono.Data.Sqlite but I still get the above issue when my phone goes to sleep.

Comment: I would look to SQLitePCL.raw : https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw

Comment: That library is written by Eric Sink. He is the guy whose article I mentioned above. He seems to have a better understanding of this than anyone, but I can't really follow what he has done in his code. If you look at this class: https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/blob/master/src/cs/sqlite3_pinvoke.cs. You will see that the DLL name is stored in a variable called SQLITE_DLL. But that text is a const set to "REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_DLL_NAME". Which is my fundamental question. What should go here? I can't follow how the code in this class fills this in...